# How do I add custom styling to a small part of Angular Material Table cell?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to change the color of the text displayed in a cell of a Material Table.
I have an array as my datasource where type is MatTableDataSource.
Some cells have regular text in them, like
rubber ducky.
I want to be able to change the color of part of that string, lets say duck.
My first idea was to add a span with some class that would do that, but the table won't let me add HTML tags, so when i do, I get the whole tag showing up as a text.
Is there a solution to this issue?

**To summarize:**

**Problem** - change color of part of text in Angular Material table (MatTableDataSource)

**Failed attempt** - insert span tag around text that needed styling. didn't work because table will display tags as regular text.

[image]

Looking for other suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change color of all cells or for specific cell ?

Comment: just part of the cell for some cells..

Comment: I realize my problem is how angular resolves {{}}, and when i add html in there, it will display the html as plain text

Comment: So now, its fine  working and you dont need any solution for this problem ? Or you are still looking for solution to this question ?

Comment: i just figured it out (after i replied here). I am using <span [innerHtml]='myvar'></span> instead of {{myvar}}. This solved it. Do you have a different approach?

Comment: myvar coming from api ?

Comment: it's a var in the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <span [innerHtml]='myvar'> instead of {{myvar}} solved it. I am not sure if there is a better solution